# How can I filter items in an array inside a template?

Tags: xml, xslt, xls

Hello I have an issue in XSL and filtering arrays.

this is my XSL trasformation:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions" xmlns:ns0="http://xmlns.sse.com/SSEPD/GIS/PublishChangeSetEBM" xmlns:tns="http://xmlns.sse.com/SSEPD/GIS/UpdateLocationEBM" xmlns:oraxsl="http://www.oracle.com/XSL/Transform/java" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:plnk="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wsbpel/2.0/plnktype" xmlns:ns1="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#" xmlns:ns3="http://iec.ch/2002/schema/CIM_difference_model#" xmlns:ns4="http://xmlns.sse.com/SSEPD/GIS/ChangeSetEBO" xmlns:ns5="http://iec.ch/TC57/2010/CIM-schema-cim15#" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:ns2="http://xmlns.sse.com/Enterprise/Common" xmlns:client="http://xmlns.oracle.com/GIS_R1_SOA/SubstationEBS/SubstationEBS" xmlns:ns7="http://www.ibm.com/maximo" xmlns:ns6="http://xmlns.oracle.com/GIS_R1_SOA/UpdateLocationProviderABCS/UpdateLocationProviderABCS" xmlns:ns8="http://xmlns.sse.com/SSEPD/GIS/UpdateLocationEBO">
<xsl:variable name="ID_HASH">#</xsl:variable>
<xsl:template match="/">
    <tns:UpdateLocationEBM>
        <tns:DataArea>
            <ns7:SyncSSENLOCATIONS>
                <ns7:SSENLOCATIONSSet>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="/ns0:PublishChangeSetRequestEBM/ns0:DataArea/ns4:ChangeSet/ns1:RDF/ns3:DifferenceModel/ns3:forwardDifferences/ns5:Substation"/>
                </ns7:SSENLOCATIONSSet>
            </ns7:SyncSSENLOCATIONS>
        </tns:DataArea>
    </tns:UpdateLocationEBM>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="/ns0:PublishChangeSetRequestEBM/ns0:DataArea/ns4:ChangeSet/ns1:RDF/ns3:DifferenceModel/ns3:forwardDifferences/ns5:Substation">
    <ns7:LOCATIONS>
        <xsl:variable name="CURRENT_SUB" select="."/>
        <ns7:CURRENT_SUB>
            <xsl:value-of select="$CURRENT_SUB"/>
        </ns7:CURRENT_SUB>
        <xsl:variable name="LOCATION" select="/ns0:PublishChangeSetRequestEBM/ns0:DataArea/ns4:ChangeSet/ns1:RDF/ns3:DifferenceModel/ns3:forwardDifferences/ns5:Location[@ns1:ID = substring-after($CURRENT_SUB/ns5:PowerSystemResource.Location/@ns1:resource, $ID_HASH)]"/>
        <xsl:variable name="VOLTAGE_LEVEL" select="/ns0:PublishChangeSetRequestEBM/ns0:DataArea/ns4:ChangeSet/ns1:RDF/ns3:DifferenceModel/ns3:forwardDifferences/ns5:VoltageLevel[ns5:VoltageLevel.Substation/@ns1:resource = concat($ID_HASH,$CURRENT_SUB/@ns1:ID)]"/>
        <ns7:VOLTAGE_LEVEL>
            <xsl:value-of select="$VOLTAGE_LEVEL"/>
        </ns7:VOLTAGE_LEVEL>
        <ns7:LOCATION>
            <xsl:value-of select="$LOCATION/ns5:Location.ngr"/>
        </ns7:LOCATION>
    </ns7:LOCATIONS>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

and this is the XML input:

```
<PublishChangeSetRequestEBM xmlns:cim="http://iec.ch/TC57/2010/CIM-schema-cim15#" xmlns:ns5="http://iec.ch/TC57/2010/CIM-schema-cim15#" xmlns:dm="http://iec.ch/2002/schema/CIM_difference_model#" xmlns:ns3="http://iec.ch/2002/schema/CIM_difference_model#" xmlns:ebo="http://xmlns.sse.com/SSEPD/GIS/ChangeSetEBO" xmlns:tns="http://xmlns.sse.com/SSEPD/GIS/PublishChangeSetEBM" xmlns="http://xmlns.sse.com/SSEPD/GIS/PublishChangeSetEBM" xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#" xmlns:ns1="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#" xmlns:ns4="http://xmlns.sse.com/SSEPD/GIS/ChangeSetEBO" xmlns:ns0="http://xmlns.sse.com/SSEPD/GIS/PublishChangeSetEBM">
<tns:DataArea>
    <ebo:ChangeSet>
        <ebo:JobID>100035</ebo:JobID>
        <ebo:FileName>Substation_XREF.rdf</ebo:FileName>
        <rdf:RDF>
            <dm:DifferenceModel rdf:about="">
                <dm:forwardDifferences rdf:parseType="Statements">
                    <cim:Substation rdf:ID="IL_SUB001">
                        <cim:PowerSystemResource.Location rdf:resource="#SUB_loc001"/>
                    </cim:Substation>
                    <cim:VoltageLevel rdf:ID="VOL_001">
                        <cim:VoltageLevel.Substation rdf:resource="#IL_SUB001"/>
                    </cim:VoltageLevel>
                    <cim:Location rdf:ID="SUB_loc001">
                        <cim:Location.ngr>SU33736744</cim:Location.ngr>
                    </cim:Location>
                </dm:forwardDifferences>
            </dm:DifferenceModel>
        </rdf:RDF>
    </ebo:ChangeSet>
</tns:DataArea>
</PublishChangeSetRequestEBM>
```

The problem that I'm having is with the variable $VOLTAGE_LEVEL. For some reason the filtering condition that I'm applying when I'm defining the variable inside the template function is not working. The tag that is using it ns7:VOLTAGE_LEVEL is empty in the output.

I've double checked with different tools and I have done different test and it looks like that the problem is the $CURRENT_SUB variable. But this is weird since the tag ns7:LOCATION is displaying the right information and it is using the variable $LOCATION that is populated by using the same approach as $VOLTAGE_LEVEL.

Can you please have a look? I'm clueless.

NOTE: I'm using stylesheet version 2.0

Kind regards
Nick

Comment: What are you currently expecting to be output in the `VOLTAGE_LEVEL` element? It is empty because you are doing `xsl:value-of` on the `cim:VoltageLevel` node, and this does not have any (non-empty) text nodes under it. Thanks!

Comment: @Tim C is right. You can rather write template on 'ns3:forwardDifferences' and change *predicate* as in answered.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. I understand your point and I think it's valid. I'm going to try it now

Comment: Thanks your comment helped me. The problem was that no text node where in the tag. Thanks again for your precious help. I'm not sure how to mark Tim C. comment as "correct answer".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this modified template and predicate value as:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <tns:UpdateLocationEBM>
        <tns:DataArea>
            <ns7:SyncSSENLOCATIONS>
                <ns7:SSENLOCATIONSSet>
                    <xsl:apply-templates
                        select="/ns0:PublishChangeSetRequestEBM/ns0:DataArea/ns4:ChangeSet/ns1:RDF/ns3:DifferenceModel/ns3:forwardDifferences/ns5:Substation" />
                </ns7:SSENLOCATIONSSet>
            </ns7:SyncSSENLOCATIONS>
        </tns:DataArea>
    </tns:UpdateLocationEBM>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template
    match="/ns0:PublishChangeSetRequestEBM/ns0:DataArea/ns4:ChangeSet/ns1:RDF/ns3:DifferenceModel/ns3:forwardDifferences/ns5:Substation">
    <ns7:LOCATIONS>
        <xsl:variable name="CURRENT_SUB" select="."/>

        <ns7:CURRENT_SUB>
            <xsl:value-of select="$CURRENT_SUB" />
        </ns7:CURRENT_SUB>

        <xsl:variable name="LOCATION"
            select="/ns0:PublishChangeSetRequestEBM/ns0:DataArea/ns4:ChangeSet/ns1:RDF/ns3:DifferenceModel/ns3:forwardDifferences/ns5:Location[@ns1:ID = substring-after($CURRENT_SUB/ns5:PowerSystemResource.Location/@ns1:resource, $ID_HASH)]" />
        <xsl:variable name="VOLTAGE_LEVEL"
            select="/ns0:PublishChangeSetRequestEBM/ns0:DataArea/ns4:ChangeSet/ns1:RDF/ns3:DifferenceModel/ns3:forwardDifferences/ns5:VoltageLevel/ns5:VoltageLevel.Substation[@ns1:resource = concat($ID_HASH,$CURRENT_SUB/@ns1:ID)]" />

        <ns7:VOLTAGE_LEVEL>
            <xsl:value-of select="$VOLTAGE_LEVEL" />
        </ns7:VOLTAGE_LEVEL>
        <ns7:LOCATION>
            <xsl:value-of select="$LOCATION/ns5:Location.ngr" />
        </ns7:LOCATION>
    </ns7:LOCATIONS>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Hi Vebbie, thanks for your response. 
I've tried your xsl but it has two problems:
1) I need to apply the transformation only to items ns5:Substation.
2) In your version the ns7:VOLTAGE_LEVEL tag is still empty.

Kind regards
Nicola

Comment: @Nick : As per your requirement 1) I have changed my answer accordingly. (back to match **ns5:Substation**) and 2) try to put value in **cim:VoltageLevel.Substation** (as it is empty). Then try again.